# Regex to match " but not \"

Tags: regex

I'm always completely at loss with regexes so I hope someone here can help.

Joomla uses this regex to validate lines of ini files:

```
/^(|(\[[^\]]*\])|([A-Z][A-Z0-9_\-]*\s*=(\s*(("[^"]*")|(_QQ_)))+))\s*(;.*)?$/
```

The lines have this format

```
JLIB_LOGIN_AUTHENTICATE="Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet."
```

Obviously `"` can't be allowed in the value part but `\"` could be. Currently this is matched by the above regex. I can see how it's matched but I can't modify the regex not to match `\"`. I tried adding `|(\Q\"\E)`to various places but no luck.

Comment: It's good that you've given an example input, but it's a shame that there is only one example. Can you provide some more valid and invalid inputs? Please specify for each input whether you want to be treated as valid and invalid. Also show for each input whether your attempted solution gives a correct or incorrect result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
"[^"]*"
```

To this:

```
"(\\"|[^"])*"
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ysI0j)

Comment: As noted below there seems to be an issue with the escaping. It works when I use `"([^"]|(\Q\"\E))*"`.

Comment: I tested it, it doesn't matter if before or after, it never matches anything. If I escape it using `\Q` and `\E` it does work. Since I really don't know a lot about regexes I can't explain why that is.

Comment: That neither produces a match with the segment before or after the `[^"]` :( Maybe it help to clarify this is used with PHP's `preg_match`.

Comment: Here's the full code: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/libraries/joomla/language/language.php#L820 I don't see anything out of order with it.

Answer (score 3):

replace `[^"]` with `([^"]|(\\"))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I tried it with this regex: `'/^(|(\[[^\]]*\])|([A-Z][A-Z0-9_\-]*\s*=(\s*(("([^"]|(\\"))*")|(_AA_)))+))\s*(;.*)?$/'` (note I replaced `_QQ_` with `_AA_`) and tested it with a line containing the `_QQ_`and it didn't work.

Comment: That didn't help either but weirdly enough this one work `'/^(|(\[[^\]]*\])|([A-Z][A-Z0-9_\-]*\s*=(\s*(("([^"]|(\Q\"\E))*")|(_AA_)))+))\s*(;.*)?$/'`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mark Byers: and then it will fail to match and will backtrack (step back), and try the second option. I don't know what kind of optimizations regex engines do, your one might perform better.

Comment: @Mark Byers: not sure either.. `*` is greedy, shouldn't it first try to match as much as possible? what does it exactly do when the expression is a compound?

Comment: +1. For the specific requirements the OP has (he only cares *if* it matches, not *how* it matches) this would work just as well as my answer. Sorry for the earlier comments - it's not important here.